# Removing an image from html5 canvas when it's dragged to a certain location

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I have an HTML5 canvas that is displaying a number of images and four description boxes. It is currently possible to drag and drop the images around the canvas, but I want to add functionality to remove an image when it is dragged to its correct description box.

I've tried writing the following function, but it does not currently seem to be doing anything... i.e. if I drag an image to its description box and drop it, it still remains on the canvas:

```
function initStage(images){
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: "container",
        width: 1000,
        height: 500
    });
    var descriptionLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    //var imagesLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var allImages = [];
    var currentScore = 0;

    var descriptionBoxes = {
        assetsDescriptionBox: {
            x: 70,
            y: 400
        },
        liabilitiesDescriptionBox: {
            x: 300,
            y: 400
        },
        incomeDescriptionBox: {
            x: 530,
            y: 400
        },
        expenditureDescriptionBox: {
            x: 760,
            y: 400
        },
    };

    /*Code to detect whether image has been dragged to correct description box */
    for (var key in sources){
        /*Anonymous function to induce scope */
        (function(){
            var privateKey = key;
            var imageSource = sources[key];

            /*Check if image has been dragged to the correct box, and add it to that box's
                array and remove from canvas if it has */
            canvasImage.on("dragend", function(){
                var descriptionBox = descriptionBoxes[privateKey];
                if(!canvasImage.inRightPlace && isNearDescriptionBox(itemImage, descriptionBox)){
                    context.remove(canvasImage);
                    /*Will need to add a line in here to add the image to the box's array */
                }
            })

        })();
    }

}
```

The code I've written is based on the tutorial that I found at: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-animals-on-the-beach-game-with-kineticjs/

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong, and how I can ensure that the image is removed from the canvas when it's dragged to its corresponding description box?

Answer (score 1):

That example bugged me because it seemed old, so I edited it a little...
http://jsfiddle.net/LTq9C/1/
...keep in mind that I cant be positive that all my edits are the best way to do things, Im new and all ;)

And here I've edited it again for you to show the image being removed...

```
    animal.on("dragend", function() {
        var outline = outlines[privKey + "_black"];
        if (!animal.inRightPlace && isNearOutline(animal, outline)) {
            animal.remove();
            animalLayer.draw();
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8S3Qq/1/

Comment: Are the JSFiddles still functioning?

Comment: @perl-user I havent looked at Kinect in ages and looks like their not, sorry.  The url I used for the link to KinectJS source doesnt work any more and I cant find a cdn or anything.  If you can find a url then just remove the old one in External Resources and replace it with that.  Sorry I cant be more help....Actually I changed the url to the one on the home page, but looking at that url I wouldnt think its permanent, but meh, here ya go.... http://jsfiddle.net/LTq9C/12/ ...looks like it dont work anywayz ;(